# committed to svn tag. What have I done? What should I do?

Tags: svn

In a moment of inattention, I edited a file in an svn checkout from a tag, and committed it.

I don't even understand the resulting state of affairs. Is the tag now pointing to my edit? If it is, is there any way to 'fix' it other than to make *another* commit that undoes the previous?

Comment: Branches and tags are just conventional names for repository copies/variants on SVN.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A tag is no different to a branch which is no different to a copy of your trunk. There is nothing special about copying the contents of your trunk to a sub directory in "tags", it's just a copy. Of course, it doesn't take up much space on the server because SVN is clever and tracks history across copies.

Just undo your last commit using svn merge like described here: http://blog.johang.se/2009/03/revert-commit-in-subversion.html